# how do you align grid with image frames in matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib

in matplotlib I'd like to use a y scale that's evenly spaced eventhough the values are not linear, is that possible ? I need this to align the grid to a filterbank plot with nonlinear frequencies. Thanks.

Guillaume

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. Maybe the easiest way is to set the tick locations manually. For example, if you have a logarithmic y-axis, but still want the grid to look evenly spaced, you could do this:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.yticks([1, 10, 100], labels=['one', 'a few', 'a lot'])
```

Comment: wow, thanks it's *exactly* what I was looking for :) so I'll use the frequency bands count as ticks (1,2,3 etc.) and the bands center frequencies array as the labels, cool ! I heared pcolormesh was more flexible scale wise, you think it has a better solution ?

Comment: Glad I could help. I'm not familiar with filterbank plots though, so I can't tell whether you need `pcolormesh`. In general, I would go with the simpler solution if it works.

Answer (score 0):

just in case someone is interested here's the final code that did the trick (in Python):

```
_freq = array of nonlinear values
_Ymin, _Ymax, _Ystep = (0, 5000, 10)
_Ymin = np.abs(_freq - _Ymin).argmin()
_Ymax = np.abs(_freq - _Ymax).argmin()
plt.ylim([_Ymin, _Ymax +1])
_yticks = np.arange(_Ymin, _Ymax +1, _Ystep)
plt.yticks(ticks= _yticks, labels= _freq[_yticks])
```